# Why my log files aren't being filled?

Tags: command-line, logs

I noticed the version of Ubuntu I deployed from image on a vps does not have a lot of the logging enabled.  I don't see any syslog or auth log.  Is there a way to restore to the default logging preferences?  There is not a GUI.  I do everything from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I mangled my own logging configuration files to make this more compelling. It took me a bit to figure out that UCF purging piece. I kept getting:

> Not replacing deleted config file /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

... even after `export UCF_FORCE_CONFMISS=1`... ucf -p did the trick, but I don't know why it came to that.

```
sudo mv -v /etc/rsyslog.conf ~
sudo mv -v /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf ~
sudo ucf -p /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install rsyslog
```